# How to use Dozer to copy data between classes without destroying the target class

Tags: java, dozer

Using the example bellow:

```
public void reload(WorkTemplateDTO workTarget) throws Exception  {
    WorkTemplateDTO work = this.load(data.getId());
    workTarget= mapper.map(work, WorkTemplateDTO.class);
}
```

The instance 'workTarget' received as argument and destination of the copy is being replaced by a new instance with data from 'work'.

I would like to know if is possible to use Dozer to just copy data from source (work) to destination (workTarget) without destroing the old instance of 'workTarget'.

Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dozer also allows object to object mapping, so you can use the mapper in following way

```
public void reload(WorkTemplateDTO workTarget) throws Exception  {
    WorkTemplateDTO work = this.load(data.getId());
    mapper.map(work, workTarget);
}
```

ref: [DozerBeanMapper](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/dozer/DozerBeanMapper.html#map(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))